# SSL 1108 Mac Issue

Tags: python, macos, ssl, discord, discord.py

I am making a bot for Discord using discord.py. I've seen multiple threads on this but are still experiencing issues. I am on Mac an every time I try to run my script in VS Code, I get this error `raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')]`

Comment: you need to pass it your own certificates ? Or maybe use an option that allows connection without it.

Answer (score 3):

As seen [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/423), you'll need to go to `Applications/Python 3.X/` and you'll see a folder called `Install Certificates.command`.

Double-click that and you should be fine when you run your bot again.

Comment: No worries! Don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you, because it could help others find the answer if they have the same issue. Good luck with the bot :^)

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue please do the below:

1. Install this package: https://pypi.org/project/certifi/
2. `pip install certifi`
3. Go to your Terminal an paste this:
   `/Applications/Python\ 3.11/Install\ Certificates.command`

Note: maybe you must change the `Python` version to your actual version